# Как сделать виртуальную машину в Android Studio в отдельном окне

Tags: android, android-studio, виртуальная-машина

Установил андройд студию только ради эмуляторов андройда.

При первом запуске всё было норм окошко с виртуальным андройдом было отдельно даже саму студию закрыть можно было окно виртуалки оставалось, а потом(не помню что я такого сделал) перезапускаю, а окно виртуалки как бы встроенно в идешку с боку, интерфейс дурацкий, мультитач по контролу не работает, скрины приложу.

Как мне вернуть как было.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О, а я себе пожалуй это включу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Снимите галочку в настройках Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, оно!,,,,,,